# Best to consume WS operations in Mulesoft

Tags: mule, mulesoft

New to Mulesoft and have a question regarding SOAP consumer for calling Web service. 
Suppose there is  a web service with a few operations. As an example the WS has operations for “createUser”, “validateUser”, “isAccountActive” and etc.
Let say “createUser” requires me to pass “userName”, “firstName”, “lastName”, “address”, “city”, “zipCode” and etc
While “validateUser” only requires “userName” only and “isAccountActive” requires “username” and “zipCode”

Suppose the information is coming as a http post in this format for createUser

```
<Service>
   <operation>CreateUser</operation>
   <userName>jdow123</userName>
   <firstName>John</firstName>
   <lastName>Dow</lastName>
   <address>123 East street</address>
   <city>NY</city>
   <zipCode>123456</zipCode>
</Service>
```

And like this for isAccountActive

```
<Service>
   <operation> isAccountActive </operation>
   <userName>jdow123</userName>
   <zipCode>123456</zipCode>
</Service>
```

So in this case does it make sense to create multiple subflows like the digram I have to handle each operation or there are better ways 
Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would still use a `sub-flow` for each operation. One, it will allow reuse later and avoid duplicating code. It will allow you to test each operation individually and allow you to easily mock each sub-flow as part of a larger test - increasing testability.

As for the mapping to each sub-flow, you are currently using a choice router - It depends on you interface for that flow. If it’s a rest api you could use APIKit in Mule to map requests to a specific flow for create vs validate for example. But it all depends on your requirements.

Comment: Is it safe to say in SOAP, one web service consumer can only handle one operation? So in my case if I want to consume both "CreateUser" and "IsAccountValid" I need to have 2 consumers?